# programmatically creating buttons and attaching div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following html

```
<tr class="forum forum_268">
    <td class="icon">
        <a href="forumdisplay.php?forumid=268"><img src="http://fi.somethingawful.com/forumicons/byob.gif" title="118527 replies in 4674 threads" alt=""></a>
    </td>
    <td class="title">
        <a class="forum" href="forumdisplay.php?forumid=268" title="Want to have a good time with friends online? Step in and have a chat. Chill out and enjoy yourselves online.">BYOB 8.2</a>
        <div class="subforums"><b>SUBFORUMS:</b> (None)<input style="float:right;" type="button" class="sb" value="Add">Test</div>
    </td>
    <td class="moderators"><a href="member.php?action=getinfo&amp;userid=85738">Jett</a>, <a href="member.php?action=getinfo&amp;userid=173896">Arnold of Soissons</a></td>
</tr>
```

I have a button inside here as you can see. Assume that this type of code is repeated 15 times or so on a page. When someone clicks on the button I need to then take the code corresponding to where they clicked.

Is there a nice way to tie the data, of this entire element, class = "forum_268", to the button so when it is clicked I can access it?

I am sure I could do something with hidden input but that is really messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this get element tr class="forum forum_268"

```
  $('.sb').click(function(event) {
     var a = $(this).parents('.forum');
  });
```

Comment: Your first answer is great but that is even more concise! I should have pointed out that jQuery was fine too, woops. This makes sense and is wonderful, thank you! Marked as answer